# Scale values between -1 and 1 with a sum of 0

Tags: statistics

I need a function that scales array of values (from -inf to inf) between -1 and 1 with a sum of 0. The closest thing that comes to mind is the softmax function. But I don't know how to convert it to the form I need.

Comment: Okay so how I understand this, is that you have some values that are real numbers with no particular upper or lower limit. Let's call this set $X$. Now, you want a (linear) function $f(x)$ so that when you form a new set $Y=f(X)$, then $\min Y = -1$ and $\max Y = 1$, right? And lastly, you want the sum to be zero? In mathematical terms that would mean $\sum_{i}f(X_i) = 0$, right? Does all this look like what you want?

Comment: @MattiP. Yes, everything is correct

Comment: I'm not sure that what you're asking is even possible in all cases. Consider the set
$$
\{ -1,~ 1,~ 1 \}
$$
The minimum is $-1$ and the maximum is $1$. But the mean is $\frac{1}{3}$. Let's try to scale this so that the conditions are fulfilled. We want $f(-1)=-1$ and $f(1) =1$. The general form of the new set is
$$
\{ f(-1), ~f(1), ~f(1) \}
$$
and the sum is of course $f(-1)+f(1)+f(1) = -1 + 1 +1 = 1 \neq 0$ ... So in this case it's impossible to have a nonzero sum.

Answer (score 1):

Matti P.'s comment shows that there is no function  which always meets this condition.

If you have the data $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n$ with minimum $a$, mean $b$ and maximum $c$ with $a <b< c$ then $$f(x_i) = \dfrac{x_i - b}{\max(c-b,b-a)}$$ will transform the data linearly so it has mean of $0$, a maximum of $1$ or less and a minimum of $-1$ or more, and at least one of $1$ and $-1$ being achieved

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed. I misunderstood Matti P.'s comment about minY and maxY - of course they shouldn't be exactly equal to -1 and 1, but their values ​​should be in the range from -1 to 1